# Why jenkins junit test result trend graph only shows failed tests, not aggregated?

Tags: jenkins, testing, graph, junit, trend

recent Jenkins versions show only failed tests in Junit test result trend graph.

[image: not aggregated, only failed or passed]

Is possible to show aggregated results, passed and failed, as before?

[image: classic aggregated graph]

Thanks!